# Problem with this command, npm install @splidejs/react-splide?

Tags: reactjs, splidejs

I'm trying to add slider in to the react app, so I tried to install splide js but while installing the library with this command `npm install @splidejs/react-splide` I'm facing the error. What would be the problem?

```
PS E:\Learn React JS\haribaba.github.io\client> npm install @splidejs/react-splide
Unrecognized token in source text.
At line:1 char:13
+ npm install  <<<< @splidejs/react-splide
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnrecognizedToken
```

Img of Error

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Powershell is parsing the @. Try using quotes like this:

```
npm install "@splidejs/react-splide"
```